# Applying a patch doesn't work

Tags: version-control

I'm having trouble with applying a patch for a Drupal module.
I thought it was as simple as using "git apply thepatch.patch," but when I do this in the main directory that holds the .git directory, I get the following error message:

> Checking patch entity_translation.admin.inc…
>   error: entity_translation.admin.inc: No such file or directory

When I do this in the directory where the files are located, nothing happens; no error is shown, but no file is changed.

It's not a problem I have with this particular patch, but I never seem to be able to apply a patch, and I just end up manually editing the files.

I would like to know the solution once and for all.

Comment: Did any of these solutions work for you?

Answer (score 17):

It is possible that the patch was rolled before the days of Git on drupal.org.

For old patches:

```
patch -p0 < thepatch.patch
```

For new patches that mysteriously fail with `git apply`:

```
patch -p1 < thepatch.patch
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow below steps:

1. Download the patch file and place it to the module folder ie. `sites/all/modules/varnish`
2. Make sure you are at the same module directory ie. `sites/all/modules/varnish`
3. Use `git init` command to start git on that repository, even if you have git initialized at drupal root.
4. Run command `git apply -v filename.patch`

Answer (score 2):

The command `git apply -v thepatch.patch` should work.

You will need to run in in the module directory which you are patching (eg. `sites/all/modules/module_name/`) and the `.patch` file should be in that directory as well.  The `-v` option is for verbose and should tell you whether the patch application was successful.

Comment: is just doesn't, tried a couple other patches but nothing ever happens.

Comment: Adding to @nmc comment, that your directory sites/all/modules does not have to be under version control. but you should have git installed.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions given for each project hosted on Drupal.org are the following (you can find them on [this page](http://drupal.org/project/views/git-instructions), for example):

> Applying a patch
>
> Download the patch to your working directory. Apply the patch with the following command:
>
> ```
> git apply -v [patchname.patch]
> ```
>
> To avoid accidentally including the patch file in future commits, remove it:
>
> ```
> rm  [patchname.patch]
> ```

The working directory is the directory containing the module files; in the case of the Views module, it's the directory containing the views.module, views.info, and views.install files you need to patch.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, in my case, the following worked for me.

patch -p1 < thepatch.patch

Comment: According to this page https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply you should use patch -p1 < thepatch.patch "If you are not using git, or if the repo isn't a local checkout of the project you wish to patch"